# C++: avoiding library-specific types in public interface

Tags: c++, friend

I'm currently working on a little game engine project in  C++ using DirectX for rendering. The rendering part of the engine consists of classes such as `Model` and `Texture`. Because I would like to keep it (relatively) simple to switch to another rendering library (e.g. OpenGL) (and because I suppose it's just good encapsulation), I would like to keep the public interfaces of these classes completely devoid of any references to DirectX types, i.e. I would like to avoid providing public functions such as `ID3D11ShaderResourceView* GetTextureHandle();`.

This becomes a problem, however, when a class such as `Model` requires the internal texture handle used by `Texture` to carry out its tasks - for instance when actually rendering the model. For simplicity's sake, let's replace DirectX with an arbitrary 3D rendering library that we'll call Lib3D. Here is an example demonstrating the issue I'm facing:

```
class Texture {
private:
    Lib3DTexture mTexture;
public:
    Texture(std::string pFileName)
        : mTexture(pFileName)
    {
    }
};

class Model {
private:
    Texture* mTexture;
    Lib3DModel mModel;
public:
    Model(std::string pFileName, Texture* pTexture)
        : mTexture(pTexture), mModel(pFileName)
    {
    }
    void Render()
    {
        mModel.RenderWithTexture( /* how do I get the Lib3DTexture member from Texture? */ );
    }
};
```

Of course, I could provide a public `GetTextureHandle` function in `Texture` that simply returns a pointer to `mTexture`, but this would mean that if I change the underlying rendering library, I would also have to change the type returned by that function, thus changing the public interface of `Texture`. Worse yet, maybe the new library isn't even structured the same way, meaning I'd have to provide entirely new functions!

The best solution I can think of is making `Model` a friend of `Texture` so that it can access `Texture`'s members directly. This seems slightly unwieldy, however, as I add more classes that make use of `Texture`. I have never used friendship much at all, so I'm not sure if this is even an acceptable usage case.

So, my questions are:

- Is declaring Model a friend of Texture an acceptable use of
  friendship? Would it be a good solution?
- If no, what would you
  recommend? Do I need to redesign my class structure
  completely? In that case, any tips?

*PS: I realize that the title is not very descriptive and I apologize for that, but I didn't really know how to put it.*

Comment: you can probably get a much cleaner approach using a good building system such as cmake and let the configuration select the right source code for the right platform. The idea is to keep the same headers but use different implementations, different .cpp files, based on what your configuration is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it is an acceptable use of friendship is debatable. With every feature, even good ones, that you use, you risk that anti-patterns form in your code. So just use it with moderation and be cautious for anti-patterns.

While you can use friendships you can also simply use inheritance i.e. IGLTexture : ITexture and cast to the appropriate interface wherever implementation detail needs to be accessed. For instance IGLTexture could expose everything opengl related.

And there is even another paradigm that could be used. pimpl which stands for 
private implementation. In short rather than exposing implementation detail 
within the class, you just supply all implementation detail in a class whose implementation is unspecified publicly. I've been using this approach myself with little second regrets.

```
//header
class Texture
{
    int width, height, depth;
    struct Impl;    
    char reserved[32];
    *Impl impl;
    Texture();
    ...
};

//cpp
struct Texture::Impl
{
    union
    {
        int myopenglhandle;
        void* mydirectxpointer;
    };
};

Texture::Texture()
{
   impl = new (reserved) Impl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to abstract this mo-fo.

```
class TextureBase{
public:
 virtual Pixels* getTexture() = 0;
 virtual ~TextureBase(){}
};
class Lib3DTexture: public TextureBase {
private:
    Lib3DTexture mTexture;
public:
    Texture(std::string pFileName)
        : mTexture(pFileName)
    {
    }
    Pixels* getTexture(){ return mTexture.pixels(); }
};

class Renderable{
public:
 virtual void render()const = 0;
 virtual ~Renderable(){}
};

class ModelBase: public Renderable{
public:
  virtual ModelData* getModelData() = 0;
  virtual ~ModelBase(){}
};

class Lib3DModel : ModelBase{
private:
  TextureBase* texture;
  ModelBase* model;
public:
 Lib3DModel(std::string pFileName, Texture* pTexture): mTexture(pTexture), mModel(pFileName){}
 void render()const{
   model.renderWithTexture( texture.getPixels() );
 }
};

class World: public Renderable{
private:
 std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Renderable> > visibleData;
public:
 void render()const{
   for_each(visiableData.begin(),visiableData.end(),std::mem_fun(Renderable::render));
 }
};
```

you get the idea, not guaranteeing it compiles but just to give you an idea.Also check out user2384250 comment, good idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make `Texture` a template with a default template parameter using DirectX.

So you can do this:

```
template<typename UnderlyingType = Lib3DTexture> class Texture {
private:
    UnderlyingType mTexture;
public:
    Texture(std::string pFileName)
        : mTexture(pFileName)
    {
    }

    UnderlyingType UnderlyingTexture(); //returns UnderlyingType, no matter which library you use
};
```

I think this could be a clean way of solving that problem, and easily allowing the switching out of underlying libraries.

Comment: I thought about this approach, but what if the new library doesn't use these handles in the same way? Perhaps one library doesn't require them at all, while one requires two - for instance both `GetTexture` and `GetTextureDescription`. Of course this is unlikely in practice, but I guess the root of the problem is that I do not want to publicly expose any functions that may change.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 2 APIs are mutually exclusive and since you probably don't need to switch between the 2 at runtime, I think you should aim at building 2 different executables, one for each of the underlying API.
By that I mean use:

```
#if OpenGL_implementation
  ...
#else // DirectX
  ...
#if
```

This may or may not be the sexy solution you were looking for. But I believe this is the cleaner and simpler solution. Going with heavy template use (resp. heavy polymorphic behaviour) will probably cause even more code bloat than an #if solution and it will also compile (resp. run) slower as well. :)

In other words, if you can afford to have the 2 behaviours you want in 2 different executables, you should not allow this to have an impact on your software architecture. Just build 2 sexy, twin software solutions instead of 1 fat one. :)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, using C++ inheritance for those sort of problems often ends a quite complex and unmaintainable project.

There are basically two solutions:

1. Abstract all data types, making them not depend on the rendering layer at all. You will have to copy some data structures from rendering layer, but you only need to replace rendering code.
2. Choose a portable render layer (OpenGL) and stick to it.

Comment: That second option is looking increasingly appealing. :)